# Prevent Chrome from opening certain links in certain apps

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android

The Stack Exchange app is a good one but I don't like it, because whenever I install it, Google Chrome will open all links to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in the app rather than a new tab.

Can I make Chrome permanently ignore this app and open any SO/SE links itself?

Android 7.1.2, Google Chrome 62.0.3202.84

Comment: see if you can configure [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith&hl=en) to prevent that

Comment: @beeshyams probably no. Google search even show results as "Open in Stack Exchange app"

Comment: Try downloading Chromer app. I use it for opposite case. Opening pages from XDA app on chromer instead of app. May help in your case

Comment: You could try the trick in my answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187987/131553

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is the way to do it:

1. Open the app info of stack exchange app in your phone.
2. Click on "Open by default".
   [image: Bottom of the image]
3. In the next screen that appears, click "Clear Defaults".
4. That should give you a prompt whenever you click on an SO link.
5. Just select chrome and it will open in chrome only.

Comment: Doesn't really help me. I've already uninstalled the app, it doesn't exist on the app store any more, and Google still tries to open links to the stack-exchange app.